# Checking amount of booleans that are true, and executing differently depending on the amount

Tags: java

So I'm trying to check multiple booleans (6), and want to execute different code if more than one, two, three, etc. are true.

So here is an example:

```
public static boolean x;
public static boolean y;
public static boolean z;
public static boolean a;
public static boolean b;
public static boolean c;
public static int amtTrue;
//if x & y are true, then set amtTrue to 1
//if y & z AND x & y are true, then set amtTrue to 2;
//keep iterating though all possiblilites
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you provide an example of this? It is very hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: It is indeed very broad what you are asking !

Comment: Are these booleans in an array? In 6 variables? In a list? In a house? With a mouse?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int i = 0;

for(boolean b : array)
    if(b) i++;

switch(i){
case 0:

case 1:

case 2:

}
```

Answer (score 2):

With only six booleans efficiency should not matter at all, so you could concentrate on making the most readable solution.

One approach is to make a variable-argument helper method that does the counting in a loop, like this:

```
public static int countTrue(boolean... x) {
    int count = 0;
    for (boolean b : x) {
        if (b) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

You can call it from your `if` condition as follows, for an easy-to-read solution:

```
if (countTrue(bool1, bool2, bool3, bool4, bool5, bool6) > 4) {
    ...
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/OiJXuE)